# How to give credit to short term undergraduate research assistants?

Tags: authorship, research-undergraduate

My field is applied mathematics, and I regularly hire short term undergraduate students as research assistants
to work on various projects.

Most students, for a variety of reasons,
cannot make any substantial contributions,
yet most of them end up making a tiny but nonzero amount of contribution.
Since the main subject is mathematics,
it is usually difficult to quantify/describe the contributions.
E.g., a student notice some patterns in some numerical simulation,
which, years later, leads to a theorem.
Or a student run some numerical computations,
and eliminated some hypothesis.

What is the standard way of giving credit to such student making epsilon amount of contributions?

Comment: Reward epsilon contributions with a delta amount of money?  Or maybe the reverse? :)

Answer (score 4):

If students contribute but do not meet the authorship criteria for your field of research, acknowledge their contributions in your paper.